# Aliases for Multi-Column Sort

Tags: database, sorting, computer-science, terminology

What are some other names for a multi-column sort?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're after, but if you use a "stable" sorting algorithm, you can sort based on one column, then sort on a second column (and so on), and it will behave as though you did a multi-column sort.

Comment: Thanks xscott!  Thanks exactly what I was after.